# Lightning Component: window.URL.createObjectURL Method is not available after Locker Service is Enabled

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have a component that uploads files as Attachments on Cases in Community.
It's based on the Tutorial by Peter Knolle
I am using the following line of Code to assign a Link to the attached Files.

`window.URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);`

and then using the below line to revoke the URL created if the attachment is removed.

`window.URL.revokeObjectURL(filePath);`

Now this used to work fine when LockerService is disabled. But after enabling Locker Service, the following `console.log(window.URL);` returns `undefined`

Alos, I am using the Napili Template Summer'16 Version.

Thank you.

Comment: Let me look into it. This one is a newer API, but it's probably safe to expose.

Comment: Hey! Can I know how soon will this be implemented. Thanks

Comment: @JFParadis Hi! Is this available now. Waiting for the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in a patch and should have been released to your org sometime last month. Sorry we never followed up here to inform you. Please try the code again with LockerService enabled to verify.

Comment: It throws error still. as URL.createObjectURL and window.URL.createObjectURL come as undefined inside lightning component functions. :(

Comment: @aniltilanthe Can you please provide repro for your scenario and what browser you are using? window.URL, window.URL.createObjectURL, URL and URL.createObjectURL all return expect values in our test environments. We will investigate in what situation it is returning an undefined, once we have the repo.

Comment: same here: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`  Dropping to API 39 makes the issue disappear.

Comment: @TrevorBliss Looks like we are not able to create  Blob of type application/pdf in Winter 19. Is that a bug ?