# URL.createObjectURL not working in lightning

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning, locker-service

This might relate to LockerService([Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132197/lightning-component-window-url-createobjecturl-method-is-not-available-after-lo)).

I try to use URL.createObjectURL on a vf page. Works fine in classic but in lightning it will give me "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or Salesforce1."

This is not working

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
if (link.download !== undefined) { // HTML5
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.href = url;
  link.download = filename;
  link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

This works but I can't change the filename then

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url); // works
```

Comment: (Possibly) Related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/167864.